# Is it possible and how "Giving credit for a change" for Mercurial/Git as in Bazaar?

Tags: git, mercurial, bazaar

[Bazaar support adding meta data to commit to record](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-guide/recording_changes.html)  who the actual author of a change is vs. the person who commits the change:

```
  $ bzr commit --author "Jane Rey <jrey@example.com>" \
               --author "John Doe <jdoe@example.com>"
```

After adding this meta data it accessible via `bzr log`, like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
revno: 105661
fixes bug(s): http://debbugs.gnu.org/9414
author: Oleksandr Gavenko 
committer: Juri Linkov 
branch nick: trunk
timestamp: Mon 2011-09-05 12:55:11 +0300
message:
  * lisp/progmodes/grep.el (rgrep): Add "-type d".
```

It is possible embed such metadata in commit for Mercurial/Git?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In git you have the similar command:

```
git commit --author="Name <name@example.com>"
```

But it usually comes from pre-set config values.

Hg has a similar flag for setting the user, but does not make a distinction between author and committer. But there is an [extension to do that](https://bitbucket.org/ede/committer).

Both git and hg do not have the concept of setting multiple authors for a commit. Though that is usually done in the commit message in some pre-determined way / convention in the team

Comment: For Mercurial, I would recommend to just mention that person in the commit message. The meta-data added by that extension won’t be visible unless the viewer also has that extension installed, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Mercurial has no such ability by default. There is no way to specify a "committer" vs an "author" directly. Similarly there is support for only one author.

Comment: You say that this is not possible by default. Is this mean that some external extension allow such thing? Do you know one?

Answer (score 1):

Such metadata is embedded by default in git. To see it just try tying `git log`. You'll see all the metadata associated with each commit. You can set your username and email as specified in this [tutorial](http://book.git-scm.com/2_setup_and_initialization.html). Essentially you can set your email and name like this:

> $ git config --global user.name "Scott Chacon"
>
> $ git config --global user.email "schacon@gmail.com"

Also, git has a fun command called [blame](http://book.git-scm.com/5_finding_issues_-_git_blame.html) which lets you see who changed exactly what line.

Comment: You provide info that I already know... I am looking for more advanced case there user can not directly commit but can sen patches. And I look to ability when regular developer apply patch to embed original author name to commit metadata.

Comment: Sorry, but you never specified what you did and didn't know in your question. You should be more specific next time.

Comment: A suppose that this clean flow from context ))